# How to use a state value with map function to display repeat ui in react component

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have a `react` component that I have a `state` value that I want to use in a `.map` function in order to show repeat ui.

```
class ReviewerRequirements extends Component {
  state = {
    reviewPositions: 2
  }

  showSkillsModalUI = () => {
    const { reviewPositions } = this.state;

    var skills = reviewPositions; // user defined length
    for(var i = 0; i < skills.length; i++) {
      return <li>Value</li>[i];
     }
   }
```

Comment: mention the problem you are facing, issues with this code are, you are not returning the result of the map, `return reviewPositions.map....` and `reviewPositions` is a number not array.

Comment: map is for arrays, not numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Problem :** you want to repeat the UI based on value in **reviewPositions**

`map` can be used on a array, but what you have is a number, i would suggest you converting this into a array and using the same for `map`.

```
    var data = [];
    var length = reviewPositions; // user defined length

    for(var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        data.push('undefined');
    }

    const lis = data.map((position, index) => {
      return (
          <li key={index}>
            <div className="two wide column">
              <p>Role</p>
            </div>
            <div className="two wide column">
              <p># of days required</p>
            </div>
            <div className="two wide column">
              <p>From Date</p>
            </div>
            <div className="two wide column">
              <p>To Date</p>
            </div>
            <div className="two wide column">
              <p>Language Skills</p>
            </div>
            <div className="four wide column">
              <p>Content Area Skills</p>
            </div>
            <div className="two wide column">
              <p>Other Skills</p>
            </div>
          </li>
      );
    });

    render(){
      return <ul className="ui grid">
      {lis}
      </ul>
    }
```

Comment: This should work. But, why don't you directly push the list to `data` and return it directly? Mapping is not necessary for that situation I guess. So, just create the array and return it directly.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
//this below code generate the n number of array based on your reviewPositions
Array.from(new Array(reviewPositions),(val,index)=>index+1)
//if reviewPositions = 2 
//result  [1,2]
```

```js
class ReviewerRequirements extends Component {
  state = {
    reviewPositions: 2
  }
  
  showSkillsModalUI = () => {
    const { reviewPositions } = this.state;

   Array.from(new Array(reviewPositions),(val,index)=>index+1)
   .map((position, index) => {
      return (
        <ul className="ui grid">
          <li key={index}>
            <div className="two wide column">
              <p>Role</p>
            </div>
            <div className="two wide column">
              <p># of days required</p>
            </div>
            <div className="two wide column">
              <p>From Date</p>
            </div>
            <div className="two wide column">
              <p>To Date</p>
            </div>
            <div className="two wide column">
              <p>Language Skills</p>
            </div>
            <div className="four wide column">
              <p>Content Area Skills</p>
            </div>
            <div className="two wide column">
              <p>Other Skills</p>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      );
    });
  };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create an array based on the number in your state and return it. Then you can use that result anywhere in your app.

```js
class ReviewerRequirements extends React.Component {
  state = {
    reviewPositions: 2
  }

  showSkillsModalUI = () => {
    const { reviewPositions } = this.state;
    const list = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < reviewPositions; i = i + 1) {
      list.push(
        // Find a good key instead of using the iterator here.
        <li key={i}>Value</li>
      )
    }

    return list;
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        Some other thing here.
        {this.showSkillsModalUI()}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<ReviewerRequirements />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did

```js
showSkillsModalCategoryUI = () => {
    const {
      reviewPositions,
      noOfDays,
      options,
      startDate,
      endDate,
    } = this.state;

    var data = [];
    var length = reviewPositions; // user defined length

    for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
      data.push('undefined');
    }

    const row = data.map((position, index) => {
      return (
        <div key={index}>
          <List.Item>
            <div className="ui grid">
              <div className="two wide column">
                <p>Role</p>
              </div>
              <div className="two wide column">
                <Dropdown
                  options={options}
                  placeholder="# of Days"
                  search
                  selection
                  fluid
                  allowAdditions
                  value={noOfDays}
                  onAddItem={this.handleNumberOfDaysAddition}
                  onChange={this.handleNumberOfDaysChange}
                />
              </div>
              <div className="two wide column">
                <Form.Field
                  name="startDate"
                  label={'Start Date'}
                  control={DatePicker}
                  placeholder="Please select start Date"
                  isClearable={true}
                  selected={startDate && startDate}
                  selectsStart
                  minDate={moment()}
                  startDate={startDate && startDate}
                  onChange={this.handleStartDateChange}
                />
              </div>
              <div className="two wide column">
                <Form.Field
                  name="endDate"
                  label={'End Date'}
                  control={DatePicker}
                  placeholder="Please select end date"
                  isClearable={true}
                  selected={endDate && endDate}
                  selectsEnd
                  startDate={startDate && startDate}
                  minDate={startDate && startDate}
                  endDate={endDate}
                  onChange={this.handleEndDateChange}
                />
              </div>
              <div className="two wide column">
                <p>Language Skills</p>
              </div>
              <div className="four wide column">
                <p>Content Area Skills</p>
              </div>
              <div className="two wide column">
                <p>Other Skills</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </List.Item>
        </div>
      );
    });
    return row;
  };
```